# Trying to connect to Salesforce with PubSub API's gRPC, but on subscribe topic getting error-code: "sfdc.platform.eventbus.grpc.topic.meta.permission"

Tags: api, permissions, metadata, node.js, grpc

I'm trying to connect to Salesforce with gRPC from NodeJS environment using https://github.com/pozil/pub-sub-api-node-client/ package.

The connection works, but I'm getting the following error when I try to subscribe to any change event channel:

```json
{
   "code":7,
   "details":"An error occurred while getting the metadata for org CORE/prod/00DWy000000YexVMAS and topic /data/AccountChangeEvents. Ensure the credentials and topic name are correct. rpcId: xxxxxxxxxx",
   "metadata":{
      "content-type":[
         "application/grpc"
      ],
      "error-code":[
         "sfdc.platform.eventbus.grpc.topic.meta.permission"
      ],
      "rpc-id":[
         "xxxxxxxxxx"
      ],
      "type":[
         "Subscribe"
      ]
   }
}
```

The credentials I'm using are oauth2 client credentials, the app is set up accordingly.
Here is the configuration of the app:

**Settings**

Selected OAuth Scopes:

- Full access (full)
- Perform requests at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)

Enable Client Credentials Flow: checked

**OAuth Policies**

Permitted Users: All users may self-authorize

IP Relaxation: Enforce IP restrictions

Usage: View OAuth Usage

Refresh Token Policy: Refresh token is valid until revoked

Single Logout: Single Logout disabled

Application Permissions: Perform requests at any time, Full access

**Client Credentials Flow**

Run As [System Administrator user]

I'm assuming from the error code that it's a permission issue in the portal. Since I'm a novice user of salesforce and there is absolutely no information anywhere why I'm getting this error, I'd like to invite you to come up with suggestions.